# How can I get just the keys out of an object without using Object.keys();?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been stuck on a teaching exercise for the better part of 2 days, and I decided I needed some help.

I have to write a function called keys that returns an array of all the keys in the object without using object.keys();.

I was able to turn everything into a string simply enough, and print everything using object.values(); but now I want to take what I obtained using object.values, and return just the key(As right now it returns key and value I.E - A:1, B:2, C:3 I want just ABC).

It should return an array like `['A', 'B', 'C']`

So far, this is a code I was trying. Please be kind, I am doing my best!

```
function keys(json) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);

*//My code starts here*
    const keys = Object.values(obj);
    keys.toString();
    for (const [key] of Object.Entries(obj)) {
        return(key);
    }
*//My code ends here*

}
```

There is "inputs" that test my code, they are below and represented in obj

first input:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
```

second input:

```
{"first":"Matt","last":"Lane"}
```

third input:

```
{}
```

Comment: Do you need to use `Object.values`?

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise?

Comment: You can't get keys out of `Object.values`. You don't even use `Object.values` in your code, you use `Object.entries`, but you return immediately

Answer (score 3):

You can use `for..in` loop

```js
function keys(json) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(json)
  const keys = []
  for (const key in obj) {
    keys.push(key)
  }
  return keys
}

console.log(keys('{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}'))
console.log(keys('{"first":"Matt","last":"Lane"}'))
console.log(keys('{}'))
```

Comment: Hi thank you!

Since obj gives me my values, and they're not prewritten as your code shows; can I just do console.log(keys(obj)) for this?

Or better yet: return(keys(obj));

Comment: *Since obj gives me my values, and they're not prewritten* - I don't know how the runtime you are using works

Comment: Basically this code will be submitted 3 separate times, using 3 separate inputs(the ones I wrote above.) So when I make this, it has to work for any input the runtime gives. I can't modify it once the test is run, and it will run 3 times with 3 different inputs. 

Additionally, I definitely need to turn the array into a string beforehand.

Comment: @MikeyK I turned the array into string with `join`. Also, you described how the `keys` functions works, these calls are usually run by the runtime. Are you trying to solve a codewars kata or something?

Comment: Got it, it did give an error similar to what I had before. The internet told me it was an issue with the array not becoming a string.

And no, I'm in a bootcamp and this is one of the practice questions I need to complete. I've just tried everything I could think of, and went over the material in the course several times and I just can't seem to get this one down. I got the first 5 alright, this is question #6. If you'd like a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/kZC4f5w

Comment: It says that you have to return an array. You are getting an error because it returns a string. You didn't say you have to have an array before

Comment: Understood and apologies. When I turned it into a string it stopped giving me any errors. I do see string_array but it also says it accepts a STRING json so that compiled with the error going away when I turned it into a string made me think: string is correct.

Comment: Assuming you don't want inherited keys, don't forget a `hasOwnProperty(key)` check before `push`ing the key